# How to start an elevated Windows application as another user in a single step?

Tags: c#, windows, manifest, uac, runas

I have an application that requires administrator permissions. It has a manifest with the required security settings:

```
<requestedExecutionLevel level="requireAdministrator" uiAccess="false" />
```

Since a regular user shall be able to run this program, the installer adds a technical user having administrator permissions. The user now calls a launcher application that tries to use this account and the stored password to call the target application in an elevated context.

The launcher contains the following setting in its manifest:

```
<requestedExecutionLevel  level="asInvoker" uiAccess="false" />
```

When calling the target application, I'm able to switch the user **or** elevate the context but not both. This is my (simplified) attempt:

```
public static Process RunElevatedIn(string userDomain, string userName, string userPassword, string workingDirectory, string programPath, string arguments)
{
    if (userName != null)
    {
        // try to start with technical user credentials
        try
        {
            var processStartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo
            {
                UseShellExecute = false,
                FileName = programPath,
                Arguments = arguments,
                UserName = userName,
                Password = userPassword,
                Domain = userDomain,
                WorkingDirectory = workingDirectory,
            };
            return Process.Start(processStartInfo);
        }
        catch (Exception exception)
        {
            // Log error and continue with default UAC method
        }
    }

    // try elevation using UAC
    {
        var processStartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo
        {
            UseShellExecute = true,
            FileName = programPath,
            Arguments = arguments,
            Verb = "runas",
            WorkingDirectory = workingDirectory,
        };
        return Process.Start(processStartInfo);
    }
}
```

When running this code a non-privileged user I get an error (from the first `catch`-clause):

```
System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception (0x80004005): the requested operation requires elevated privileges*
```

*) translated from localized error message (I hate this!)

I believe is due to switching to the right user, but failing to elevate into the administrator context. I hoped that specifying a proper manifest made Windows start the UAC to request a confirmation about the elevation from the user.

According to my search results, most hits were about people trying to circumvent the UAC entirely. This ist *not* my goal. The user may still be prompted with an elevation request, but shall not be asked for any credentials.

**Further investigations**

I tested my launcher with `regedit.exe` as target. `regedit.exe` has the following manifest and allows normal users to start it:

```
<requestedExecutionLevel level="highestAvailable" uiAccess="false" />
```

When using the user-switch in my launcher the start fails (unprivileged) despite the user being in the "administrator" group. When I manually start `regedit.exe` as the privileged user, I have to acknowledge the UAC.

The same test with `calc.exe` (no special privileges required) works fine. Conclusion:

- Elevating permissions using the UAC works fine, but doesn't allow to switch the user.
- Switching the user when starting an application works fine, but always drops to unprivileged (even when the launcher was started with a privileged account).

I'm starting to believe that it's impossible to switch the user **and** elevate the privileges via UAC in a single call. But I fail to see *why* this would be impossible or forbidden.

Comment: UAC would be quite worthless if it were this easy to bypass it.  So it is not possible.

Comment: I explicitely stated that I don't want to bypass the UAC. What I'm trying to do is perfectly possible when I use two steps (1. switch user, 2. elevate via UAC).

Comment: It is very important to isolate operations that require elevation (such as moving them to a separate executable). Then your main executable can always run as normal users or elevated ones, while calling the other executable and request elevation whenever needed. My open source project Jexus Manager does use such an approach, https://www.jexusmanager.com/en/latest/tutorials/inplace-elevation.html

Comment: Isn't that excactly what I'm trying to do? The launcher prepares everything that can be done as normal user and then calls the elevated program for the actual changes. I just cannot use the stored credentials for directly switching to an elevated context in a single step.